# How to scroll while using FlatList in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a list to display in cards. When there are less cards it is ok. But as the cards increases, the screen does not scroll. So the cards at the bottom are not visible.

Here is my code:

```
render () {
return (
    <Block style={{ marginHorizontal: -5 }}>

            <Card>

                <FlatList
                    style={{ paddingBottom: 20, marginHorizontal: -16 }}
                    data={this.state.users}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (

                        <Card
                            containerStyle={{ paddingVertical: 10, marginBottom: -10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20, backgroundColor: 'rgb(230,239,243)', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'grey', marginHorizontal: -10 }}

                        >

                            <Text preset="bold">{item.firstName}</Text>

                        </Card>

                    )}
                />



            </Card>

    </Block>
)
}

}
```

How do I scroll the output of this code? I read many answers in stack overflow but cound not find a solution.

Comment: Don't include FlatList inside Card

Comment: I removed the card. Still not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Flatlist shouldn't have a container of  maybe change it to  or something